# How to import a python module with a name not the filename

Tags: python, c, import

I am using the [NakedMUD](http://homepages.uc.edu/~hollisgf/nakedmud.html) code base for a project. I am running into an issue in importing modules.

In *.py (Python files) they import modules with the following syntax:

```
import mudsys, mud, socket, char, hooks
```

and in C to embed Python they use:

```
mudmod = PyImport_ImportModule("char");
```

Both of these methods seem to indicate to me that is some mudsys.py, mud.py ... files somewhere in a path findable by Python. I can not locate them. I am wondering where I might look to find how they are renaming the module other then the filename. I am unsure what else would be required to locate this.

The issue is that the second import `PyImport_ImportModule()` in one case is not finding the modules and they reference a `null` pointer returned by this.

The Python documentation mentions "[Changed in version 2.6: Always uses absolute imports.](http://docs.python.org/2/c-api/import.html)" and I am suspicious that this is the part of the issue.

Of note, they override some builtin functions of Python which may also be affecting this in `__restricted_builtin__.py` and `__restricted_builtin_funcs__.py`.

```
################################################################################
#
# __restricted_builtin_funcs__.py
#
# This contains functions used by __restricted_builtin__ to do certain
# potentially dangerous actions in a safe mode
#
################################################################################
import __builtin__

def r_import(name, globals = {}, locals = {}, fromlist = []):
    '''Restricted __import__ only allows importing of specific modules'''

    ok_modules = ("mud", "obj", "char", "room", "exit", "account", "mudsock",
                  "event", "action", "random", "traceback", "utils",
                  "__restricted_builtin__")
    if name not in ok_modules:
        raise ImportError, "Untrusted module, %s" % name
    return __builtin__.__import__(name, globals, locals, fromlist)

def r_open(file, mode = "r", buf = -1):
    if mode not in ('r', 'rb'):
        raise IOError, "can't open files for writing in restricted mode"
    return open(file, mode, buf)

def r_exec(code):
    """exec is disabled in restricted mode"""
    raise NotImplementedError,"execution of code is disabled"

def r_eval(code):
    """eval is disabled in restricted mode"""
    raise NotImplementedError,"evaluating code is disabled"

def r_execfile(file):
    """executing files is disabled in restricted mode"""
    raise NotImplementedError,"executing files is disabled"

def r_reload(module):
    """reloading modules is disabled in restricted mode"""
    raise NotImplementedError, "reloading modules is disabled"

def r_unload(module):
    """unloading modules is disabled in restricted mode"""
    raise NotImplementedError, "unloading modules is disabled"
```

and

```
################################################################################
#
# __restricted_builtin__.py
#
# This module is designed to replace the __builtin__, but overwrite many of the
# functions that would allow an unscrupulous scripter to take malicious actions
#
################################################################################
from __builtin__ import *
from __restricted_builtin_funcs__ import r_import, r_open, r_execfile, r_eval, \
     r_reload, r_exec, r_unload

# override some dangerous functions with their safer versions
__import__   = r_import
execfile     = r_execfile
open         = r_open
eval         = r_eval
reload       = r_reload
```

EDIT:
`PyObject *sys = PyImport_ImportModule("sys");` is returning NULL as well.

Comment: What about <module>.__path__?

Comment: @jazzpi Could you link documentation or something? Provide an explanation on what I am looking for to explain this?

Comment: For instance, if you import the module `PyQt4`, doing `print PyQt4.__path__` should give you a path (unless it's a built-in module). In interactive mode, you can also do `help("PyQt4")`.

Comment: @jazzpi True, but the module must load for that. In my case the module is not being imported (cannot be found) and I can't determine what file the module name is referencing.

Comment: Then use help("PyQt4"). Note the `""`. The module needn't be loaded for that do work.

Comment: The original writer would have had to include proper help comments for that? Also, if import can't find the "mud" module how would help()? I get a `no Python documentation found for 'mud'` response from the Python interactive shell.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41058/discussion-between-toothlessrebel-and-jazzpi)

Comment: I think what is missing is that I want to know how you import a module based on a name that is not the file name using the function listed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those `mud`, `char` and other modules are compiled [C-code extensions](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/building.html#building-c-and-c-extensions-with-distutils), so you should look for `mud.pyd` for win or `mud.so` for unix somewhere in `site-packages`

Just took a look into the NakedMud package, it is not a standard python module with setup.py, it is compiled with `make`, so you have to look for them in nakedmood `src`/`lib` folder.

Comment: Adding a note, these are compiled under src/scripts and they are various c-interfaces to the main engine. I am a maintainer of an active NM3.8.1 source tree.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2.5 `__import__()` added the `level` parameter with a default value of `-1`. The documentation for `PyImport_ImportModule()` reads as:

> This is a simplified interface to PyImport_ImportModuleEx() below, leaving the globals and locals arguments set to NULL and level set to 0...

As shown in the question, `__import__()` was overridden with `r_import()`, a function that filtered arguments and passed them on to `__import()__`. Thus, an extra argument `level = 1` was being passed to a function accepted only four arguments.